# Scala vector scalar multiplication

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm implementing some machine learning algorithm in Apache Spark MLlib and I would like to multiply vector with scalar:

[image]

Where u_i_j_m is a Double and x_i is a vector

I've tried the following:

```
import breeze.linalg.{ DenseVector => BDV, Vector => BV}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{DenseVector, Vectors, Vector}
...

private def runAlgorithm(data: RDD[VectorWithNorm]): = {
    ...
    data.mapPartitions { data_ponts =>
        c = Array.fill(clustersNum)(BDV.zeros[Double](dim).asInstanceOf[BV[Double]])
        ...
        data_ponts.foreach { data_point =>
            ...
            u_i_j_m : Double = ....
            val temp= data_point.vector * u_i_j_m)
            // c(j) = temp
        }
    }
}
```

Where VectorWithNorm is defined as following:

```
class VectorWithNorm(val vector: Vector, val norm: Double) extends Serializable {

    def this(vector: Vector) = this(vector, Vectors.norm(vector, 2.0))
    def this(array: Array[Double]) = this(Vectors.dense(array))
    def toDense: VectorWithNorm = new  VectorWithNorm(Vectors.dense(vector.toArray), norm)
}
```

But when I build the project I get the following error:

> Error: value * is not a member of org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector
>                 val temp = (data_point.vector * u_i_j_m)

How can I do this multiplication correctly?

Comment: `u_i_j_m : Double` isn't there a `val` missing? or did you just edited it out by accident?

Comment: there is a complicated computation for u_i_j_m so I left it out.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the Spark-Scala contributors decided that they will not pick a library for underlying computations i.e. linear algebra, in Scala. Under the hood they use breeze, but scalar * and + on Spark Vector's are private, as well as other useful methods. This is quite different than python where you can use excellent numpy linear algebra library. The argument was that developers are stretched thin, that breeze was suspicious because development stalled (if I remember correctly), there was an alternative (apache.commons.math), so they decided to let the users pick which linalg library you want to use in Scala. But, prompted by some members of the community, there is now a spark-package which provides linear algebra on `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector`  - [see here](http://spark-packages.org/package/brkyvz/lazy-linalg).

Comment: Local matrices are handled with one of these (http://statr.me/2015/09/an-overview-of-linear-algebra-libraries-in-scala-java) but what to use for distributed mllib IndexedRowMatrx?

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are using sparks's [Vector](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector) trait instead of breeze's [DenseVector](http://www.scalanlp.org/api/breeze/index.html#breeze.linalg.DenseVector), that's why there is no `*` operator defined on your `data_point.vector` member.

Comment: Thanks! I did the following and it worked:



                                                                       `var temp: BDV[Double] = new BDV(data_point.vector.toArray)` 


`temp *= u_i_j_m`


`c(j) += temp`

Comment: wouldn't it be possible to use BDV for VectorWithNorm?

Comment: It would, but VectorWithNorm is defined in a different class and I only want to use it